# Paths in Euclidean space

Tags: analysis

How do I prove?.

Let $\times$ the vector product in $\mathbb{R} ^3$. Given a vector $v \in \mathbb{R} ^3$ and an integrable path $f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R} ^3$, show that $\int_{a}^{b}(v \times f(t)) dt = v \times \int_{a}^{b} f(t) dt$.

Thanks.

Comment: Well, let's start from the beginning: what have you tried?

Comment: @Guido A.: I am lost from the beginning, I do not know how to prove. I apply definitions and I just spin around.

Comment: Okay, so, here is a hint: $f$ can be written as $(f_1,f_2,f_3)$ with each $f_i$ real valued. Now, integrating a vector is by definition integrating each coordinate. Write down the explicit formula for the cross product in each case. They should coincide.

Comment: @GuidoA.: I tried just that. Anyway, thank you.

Comment: Your approach should work! I encourage you to try it again yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f = (f_1,f_2,f_3)$. To ease on the notation, let $u_i = \int_a^bf_i(t)dt$. Now,

$$
v \times \int_a^bf(t)dt = v \times (u_1,u_2,u_3) = (v_2u_3-v_3u_2,v_3u_1 -v_1u_3,v_1u_2-u_1v_2) \tag{1}
$$

and

$$
v \times (f_1,f_2,f_3) = (v_2f_3-v_3f_2,v_3f_1 -v_1f_3,v_1f_2-f_1v_2) 
$$

so

$$
\int_a (v \times f)(t)dt = (\int_a^b\left[v_2f_3-v_3f_2\right],\int_a^b\left[v_3f_1 -v_1f_3\right],\int_a^b\left[v_1f_2-f_1v_2\right]).
$$

which coincides with $(1)$ coordinate by coordinate: it suffices to use the linearity of the integral and the definition of each $u_i$.

Comment: Thank you!. Already achieved.